# Node throws an error " Cannot find type definition" only on few computers/environments

Tags: node.js, debugging

I recently took over a new project which is developed with strapi CMS.
It's written on typescript and the developers who work on it have it run on their macbooks without any issue. However, When I tried on my Windows it didn't work. I got the following error.

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-unless'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'express-unless'
```

I thought this is some problem with windows and I tried with WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.04 in Google Cloud and also in a friend's macbook with same version of node, npm and yarn with no change in error.

However, When I tried it on a docker it worked successfully. The following is the content of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:18.19.1-slim
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn global add node-gyp
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node
RUN ["yarn", "build"]
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

When I asked the current developers what they did to make it work on their laptop. They have no clue. One mentioned it took 8 days to resolve however, he doesn't remember what he did to fix the problem.

```
node -v
v18.19.1
npm -v 
10.2.4
yarn -v
1.22.22
```

Eventually I figured out that deleting the directory `.\node_modules\@types\express-unless` fixes the problem.

My question is **What caused this error? Why this error never occurs in the original developer's computer or in the docker container**.

Comment: Does the project actually list `@types/express-unless` in the package.json file? FWIW that package is deprecated and `express-unless` provides its own type definitions. Did you inherit a `node_modules` directory when taking over the project or did you do a fresh install? There are no actual types in the `@types/express-unless` package just a LICENSE, README, and package.json file, so perhaps that is why TS was complaining about not finding the types, because there are none. When you deleted the directory from your node_modules then the types provided from `express-unless` were "visible".